# Calculating z-buffer from glm::project output

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer, zbuffer, glm-math

I would like to calculate the z-buffer of an object position from the output of glm::project. The calculation of the z-buffer in the code below is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering.

**What I've tried**

```
int windowWidth = 800;
int windowHeight = 600;
float positions[] = {-42.5806f, 27.8838f, 49.9729f} // Example point
glm::mat4 model;
glm::mat4 view;
glm::mat4 proj;

view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f ),
    glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ),
    glm::vec3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f )
    );

proj = glm::perspective( 45.0f, aspect, 0.1f, 10.0f );

// Get screen coordinates from an object point
glm::vec3 screenCoords = glm::project(
   glm::vec3( positions[0], positions[1] , positions[2] ),
   view*model,
   proj,
   glm::vec4( 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight )
);

// Calculating the z-buffer
int zFar = 10;
int zNear = 0.1;
float zBufferValue = (zFar+zNear ) / ( zFar-zNear ) + ( 1/screenCoords.z) * ( ( -2*zFar*zNear ) / ( zFar - zNear ) );
```

**The problem**

The value of zBufferValue is 1 no matter how I rotate my model or which point I use. According to the wiki page the value should be between -1 (the near plane) and 1 (the far plane).

What am I doing wrong in my calculation?

Comment: Try casting the integers to floats. Plus `zNear` will be 0, not 0.1, change it to a float.

Comment: Ah yes, should have seen that one.. When rotating my model, the z-value changes from ~0.80617 as the lowest and ~0.8117 as the highest. The change is very very small and seems insignificant to calculate with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line of code is redundant.  The depth calculation is done during the projection transform (and the subsequent perspective divide).  Essentially what `glm::project` does is this:

```
// P:  projection matrix
// MV: modelview matrix
// v:  vertex to convert to screen space

vec4 result = P * MV * vec4(v, 1.0f);
result /= result.w;     // perspective divide

// convert X/Y/Z from normalized device coords to screen coords...
result.z = (result.z + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
// ...

return vec3(result);
```

It also converts the X/Y coordinates from normalized device space `[(-1, -1), (1, 1)]` to screen space `[(0, 0), (viewport_width, viewport_height)]` but since you're only concerned with the depth buffer, I left that step out above.

So ignoring the last 3 lines of your code, `screenCoords.z` should contain a depth buffer value equivalent to what you would get from [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

Of course, the actual bits stored on the graphics card depend on the size of your depth buffer and how OpenGL is set up to use it.  In particular, if you are using a custom [glDepthRange](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDepthRange.xml) the values above will be different from what is stored in the depth buffer.

Comment: Always great help from this forum. Thank you for the explanation. I have been searching for the glm::project documentation but I didn't find anything relevant. I do still have a proplem though. How do I know which point is visible and which is not? I would assume that the z-coordinate would move out of the depth range that Andreas wrote about, if the point is no longer visible? However when outputting the z-values while rotating, the values are around 0.94-0.97..

Comment: As to GLM documentation, yes, it can be lacking at times.  Most of the functions in GTC/matrix_transform.h are straight from GLU so you can just look up the gluProject documentation for example.  Often times I just open up the .inl files and look at the code though when I don't understand what some GLM function is for.

Comment: @Købmanden The `glm` documentation is quite lacking, but it's open source and header only, so you can always look at the code. `glm::project` simply mirrors gluProject, but I believe the [gluProject documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) is actually wrong (no perspective divide).

Comment: Okay, so even though I rotate my model, the points stays within the frustum and is not clipped? Then how does the glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST ); figure out, which vertices are actually visual to the user? Sorry I'm jibbering over the same thing, I don't quite get it. The reason I ask is because I need to save a part of the image around each point, and the points that are not visible should not be saved.

Comment: `GL_DEPTH_TEST` (which can be enabled or disabled, as you mention) is an entirely different beast than the viewing volume clipping (which is always done, no matter what).  Depth culling involves testing the calculated depth of each fragment (pixel) rendered against the value that already exists in the depth buffer.  If the new value is greater than the existing one, the fragment is discarded, otherwise the color, depth, etc buffers are overwritten (perhaps using a blending function for the color buffer)

Comment: There is also a concept of back face culling (`glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`) which is sometimes conflated with depth testing (aka occlusion culling).  Back face culling involves calculating the surface normal of each primitive drawn (see [example](http://glm.g-truc.net/code.html) at top of page) and discarding the entire primitive if the vector from the camera to the primitive dotted with the primitive's surface normal is positive (as this means the primitive is facing away from the camera)

Comment: Okay I see.. Since I'm using the 'glm::project' to get the screen coordinates, there is no information on the culling of the vertices. Is there a way or a function you know to determine whether the fragment have been discarded or not? The way I see it, I would need to get the z-value for every drawn vertice in order to calculate the culling myself, which seems like the wrong way of solving this..

Comment: @Købmanden "I need to save a part of the image around each point" I suggest you create a new question for that. I agree that doing culling/depth testing yourself seems like the wrong way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You applied the formula in that Wikipedia article to the wrong values. You already applied the projection matrix with glm::project, which is what the `z' = ...` formula does. So you basically apply the projection matrix twice in your code.

The depth buffer values in OpenGL are in window coordinates, and they are in the range [n,f], where n and f are set using `glDepthRange(n, f)` (defaults are 0 and 1). You can read it up in 13.6.1 in the spec. These values have nothing to do with the zNear and zFar value used in the projection matrix.

`glm::project` simply assumes these default values, and, since it outputs window coordinates, that's the value that's written to the depth buffer. So the correct code is simply:

```
float zBufferValue = screenCoords.z;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Andreas. I haven't changed the depth range, so it should be between 0 and 1. Please see my comment on bcrists answer.